# CSS Screen size

Tags: css, screen

On my site I am working on a new page. When I view it it on a bigger screen the box is to the left. I am trying to make it left to align with everything.

CSS:

```
.contactbox {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: 400px;
    left: 400px;
    padding: 12px
    background-color:#F5F5F5;
    border: 1px solid #9C9C9C;
    text-align: left;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 7px 2px #DBDBDB;
    -moz-box-shadow:2px 2px 7px 2px #DBDBDB;
    -webkit-box-shadow:2px 2px 7px 2px #DBDBDB;  
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried? (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [FAQ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `margin-left: 400px;` use `margin: 0 auto;`. This will automatically make the left and right margins equal, centering the div.

**EDIT:**

Move it 400px left like so:

```
.contactbox {
  margin: 0 auto;
  // Allow it to be moved relative to its original (centered) position
  position: relative;
  // Move to the left (left means the left edge not the direction of movement)
  left: -400px;
}
```

Comment: But I am trying to do is make to the left 400px :)